# insert multiplos registros checkbox mysql

Tags: php, mysql, array, checkbox, sql-insert

esto tentando inserir no banco de dados informaçoes de multiplos checkbox de uma vez só  , por exemplo uma noticia é relacionada a mais de uma categoria então o e so selecionar as categorias e gravar , porem esta dando este erro ,

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\painel\pg\cadamsg.php on line 19
ErroArray ( [0] => HY000 [1] => 1366 [2] => Incorrect integer value: 'Array' for column 'carteira_id' at row 1 ) 
Notice: Undefined variable: idlogado in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\painel\pg\cadamsg.php on line 32

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\painel\pg\cadamsg.php on line 19
ErroArray ( [0] => HY000 [1] => 1366 [2] => Incorrect integer value: 'Array' for column 'carteira_id' at row 1 ) 
Notice: Undefined variable: idlogado in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\painel\pg\cadamsg.php on line 32

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\painel\pg\cadamsg.php on line 19
ErroArray ( [0] => HY000 [1] => 1366 [2] => Incorrect integer value: 'Array' for column 'carteira_id' at row 1 ) 
Notice: Undefined variable: idlogado in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\painel\pg\cadamsg.php on line 32

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\painel\pg\cadamsg.php on line 19
ErroArray ( [0] => HY000 [1] => 1366 [2] => Incorrect integer value: 'Array' for column 'carteira_id' at row 1 ) 
Notice: Undefined variable: idlogado in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\painel\pg\cadamsg.php on line 32

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\painel\pg\cadamsg.php on line 19
ErroArray ( [0] => HY000 [1] => 1366 [2] => Incorrect integer value: 'Array' for column 'carteira_id' at row 1 ) 
Notice: Undefined variable: idlogado in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\painel\pg\cadamsg.php on line 32
```

apareceu varios erros porque ai estao todos checkbox selecionados aí esta o codigo

```
<?php
                  foreach ($carteira as $cart) {
                     echo '
                    <div class="checkbox i-checks">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="f_carteira[]" value="'.$cart['id'].'">
                        <i></i>
                      '.$cart["nome"].'
                      </label>
                    </div> ' ;
                  }
                        ?>
```

insert

```
<?php
          session_start();
 include '../config/config.inc.php';

        error_reporting(E_ALL);


if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {


     $carteira = $_POST['f_carteira'];

      if($carteira){
          foreach ($carteira as $car) {
            $cadastrarmensagem = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO mensagem(codigo,conteudomsg,categoria_id,carteira_id,usuario_id) VALUES(:codigo,:conteudo,:categoria,:carteira,:usuarioid)");
      $cadastrarmensagem->bindValue(":codigo",$_POST["f_codigo"]);
      $cadastrarmensagem->bindValue(":conteudo",$_POST["f_msg"]);
      $cadastrarmensagem->bindValue(":categoria",$_POST["f_cat"]);
      $cadastrarmensagem->bindValue(":carteira",$_POST["f_carteira"]);
      $cadastrarmensagem->bindValue(":usuarioid",$_POST["f_usuario"]);
      $cadastrarmensagem->execute();
      $linha = $cadastrarmensagem->rowCount();
      if($linha > 0){
         echo "Mensagem Cadastrada com Sucesso";

         header ("Location: ../index.php?pg=mensagens");
      }else {
        echo "Erro";
        //imprimindo erro da variavel de consulta
       print_r($cadastrarmensagem->errorInfo());

        echo "$idlogado";
      }
          }
      }

    }else{echo "aconteceu algum erro";}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Quando você faz `<input type="checkbox" name="f_carteira[]"` o que vem POST é um array e a conversão de array para string é a palavra *Array*. O que você pode fazer é dar um *implode* para converter para uma string com as categorias.

```
$aCategoria = ['1','2','3'];
$sCategorias = implode(",",$aCategoria);
//resultando em 1,2,3
```

Mas como o erro é *Incorrect integer value*, e você deseja salvar várias categorias, talvez seja melhor usar outra tabela para guardar as categorias, onde você salva o *id* do item e *id* da categorias para cada uma das categorias do item.

Comment: ola amigo , poderia me informar como eu faria criando uma nova tabela ?

Answer (score 2):

Como citado pelo nosso companheiro Fernando, um implode pode resolver seu problema, fazendo tudo virar uma string e aí você vai conseguir inserir.

Isso funcionaria perfeitamente, mas particularmente, eu prefiro usar JSON ao invés de uma string com vírgulas. No seu caso os dois funcionariam, porém, se um dos valores do array fosse um outro array, não iria funcionar com só um implode.

Exemplo com JSON:

```
<?php 
$bolso = array('seda', 'bic', 'green');
$json = json_encode($bolso);
// $json é igual a uma string: ["seda", "bic", "green"]
```

Depois você pode trabalhar com os dados novamente da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php
$json = '["seda", "bic", "green"]';
$bolso = json_decode($json, true);
//bolso é igual a um array: array('seda', 'bic', 'green')
```

É importante lembrar de que se o segundo argumento do json_decode() não for true, ao invés de te retornar um array, vai retornar um objeto (da pra trabalhar da mesma forma em muitos aspectos, mas por exemplo, um foreach não iria funcionar se fosse um objeto).

Comment: poderia me demonstrar um exemplo pratico para meu problema ?

Comment: Bem lembrado Ryzinho, se for um array de array não funcionaria com o implode, o JSON um boa solução também, já usei em alguns casos, o único problema que vale se atentar é se vamos usar essa coluna como filtro nas consultas, já tive problemas com isso. Por isso sugerir usar uma outra tabela.

Comment: Bem observado Fernando. 
Alí em baixo na resposta do Thalles ele colocou o seguinte:
    
     $carteira = $_POST['f_carteira'];
     $jsoncart = json_encode($carteira);

Isso deu o erro do foreach pois o $jsoncart é nesse caso um objeto, e não um array. Deve-se usar: $jsoncart = json_encode($carteira, true); para se criar um array de um json.

Answer (score -1):

Bom pessoal , nenhuma das situaçoes deram certo tentei com json fazendo assim

```
 $carteira = $_POST['f_carteira'];
 $jsoncart = json_encode($carteira);
```

retornou esse erro :

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

e com implode

```
 $carteira = $_POST['f_carteira'];
 $scarteira = implode(",",$carteira);
```

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: ok amigo , infelizmente não tenho conhecimento total da ferramenta ,

Comment: Percebo. Mas o conhecimento vem com a prática, então prestando atenção nas dicas, vc pega o jeito. Experimente com json_decode no lugar do encode. Minha sugestão, caso não consiga resolver com o decode é abrir uma pergunta separada e colar o código completo e deletar essa sua nova duvida da pergunta atual, deixando como estava (a pergunta original e as respostas ja dadas). PS: Se a resposta aceita estava boa, e foi você que mudou o código, dá pra deixar ela aceita como estava (pq ai não foi culpa de quem respondeu que houve uma nova situação no código)